# Does Java has Android's Handler like IPC mechanism?

Tags: java, android, ipc

In Android, it is easier to communicate between threads using Handler/Looper frameworks. Does Java have similar mechanisms to communicate across threads?

Comment: To communicate something across threads, all you need to do is use normal variables (or sometimes through volatile/atomic/varhandle). Be more specific: what kind of communication do you need?

Comment: IPC stands for Inter-Process Communication. If you're looking for Inter-Thread Communication, check this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inter-thread-communication-java/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by implementing the `producer-Consumer` pattern using `wait()` and `notify()` methods in Java.
[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-solution-using-threads-java/) is an example.